# MVC 3 accessing model errors via ajax

Tags: .net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a fairly large MVC 3 web application. Various programmers of varying skills have worked on this for the past few years and so understanding it all is a slow and frustrating process.

My main problem at the moment is trying to understand what exactly the previous workers were attempting with the following code:

Here is the view `CreatePartial` (despite not being used as a partial view)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<RetainedAvailability.ViewModels.CreateAccountViewModel>" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SetupCreateView();
    $(document).ready(function () { $('input:submit,button').button(); });
</script>
    <h2>Create a New Account</h2>
    <p>
        Use the form below to create a new account. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%:ViewData["PasswordLength"]%> characters in length.
    </p>

<form id="CreateForm" runat="server">
        <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")%>
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.User.UserName)%>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.UserName)%>
                    <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.UserName)%>
                </div>

                <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.Email)%>
                <%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User.Email)%>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.User.Password)%>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%:Html.PasswordFor(m => m.User.Password)%>
                    <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.Password)%>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.User.ConfirmPassword)%>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%:Html.PasswordFor(m => m.User.ConfirmPassword)%>
                    <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.ConfirmPassword)%>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.User.Role)%>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%:Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User.Role, Model.Roles)%>
                    <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.Role)%>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
</form>
```

Here is the relevant controller method

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,StationManager")]
public ActionResult CreatePartial(RegisterModel User)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user and get status
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(User.UserName, User.Password, User.Email);

        // If successful registration, update the db
        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            // Link role and user
            Roles.AddUserToRole(User.UserName, User.Role);
            // Link station and user
            _repository.LinkUserToStation(User.UserName, (Guid) Session["StationID"]);
            // Save tables
            _repository.SaveChanges();

            // Create success notification
            var res = new AjaxResponse<CrewMember>
            {
                Data = null,
                IsSuccess = true,
                GrowlNotification = "Created " + User.UserName
            };
            // Return notification
            return new JsonResult {Data = res, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;

    var Errors = ModelState.Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Any()).Select(ee => ee.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage).ToList();

    var res1 = new AjaxResponse<dynamic>
    {
        Data = null,
        IsSuccess = false,
        Errors =
            ModelState.Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Any()).Select(
                ee => ee.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage).ToList()
    };

    return new JsonResult {Data = res1, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
}
```

So as you can see any model errors are encapsulated within an `AjaxResponse` and then passed as a `JsonResult`, which I expect is passed back to the view.

The problem is once the form in the view is used with invalid data (which is what I'm testing for) nothing happens. No error messages. I assume some javascript is missing on the view-end that will make use of the `JsonResult`. The validation classes in the view don't appear to be used.

There is no view returned either, just the `JsonResult`, is this acceptable for ASP.NET MVC?

**EDIT**

The following JS handles the validation for the form. It applies the errors to the DOM manually, despite the view already making use of validation entities. Is it just me or is this a needlessly verbose way of validating a form?

```
    function ShowValidationErrors(data) {
        $('#CreateForm input[type=text]').removeClass("ui-state-error");
        $('#CreateForm label').css('font-weight', 'normal');
        $('.field-validation-error').remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Errors.length; i++) {
            $('#CreateForm label[for=' + recordName + '_' + data.Errors[i].Target + '], #CreateForm label[for=' + data.Errors[i].Target + ']').css('font-weight', 'bold');
            //     $('#CreateForm #' + recordName + '_' + data.Errors[i].Target +', #CreateForm #' + data.Errors[i].Target).attr('class', 'input-validation-error');
            $('#CreateForm #' + recordName + '_' + data.Errors[i].Target + ', #CreateForm #' + data.Errors[i].Target).addClass("ui-state-error");
            $('<p class="field-validation-error">* ' + data.Errors[i].Message + '</p>').insertAfter('#CreateForm #' + recordName + '_' + data.Errors[i].Target);
            $('<p class="field-validation-error">* ' + data.Errors[i].Message + '</p>').insertAfter('#CreateForm #' + data.Errors[i].Target);
            $('.input-validation-error:first').focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This function SetupCreateView probably is the one that set the json result for each specific field! Take a look!

Comment: Thanks for that. Found some interesting code.